# Create button array for jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to create a button array then append it to a jQuery dialog?

Something along these lines.  Forgive my errorful code within the for loop, just not sure how to do this at all.

```
function setAutoDialog()
{
    var testArray = ["T1", "T2"];
    $('#autoDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 'auto',
    });
    var buttons = {};
    for(var i=0; i<testArray.length; i++){
        buttons += [testArray[ix] : Test()]
    }
    $('#autoDialog').dialog('option', 'buttons', buttons);
}

function Test()
{
    alert("worked");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
function setAutoDialog(){
    var testArray = ["T1", "T2"];

    var testFunction = function () {
        alert("worked");
    }

    var myButtons = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++){
        myButtons[testArray[i]] = testFunction;
    }

    $('#autoDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 'auto',
        buttons : myButtons
    }); 
}
```

"For instance on click instead of alert(worked) I want to get alert(buttonClicked.val())?" It would be something like :

```
function setAutoDialog(){
    var testArray = ["T1", "T2"];

    var myButtons = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++){
        var testFunction = function () {
            alert(testArray[i]);
        }

        myButtons[testArray[i]] = testFunction;
    }

    $('#autoDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 'auto',
        buttons : myButtons
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks!  I thought it would work similar to that but I couldn't figure out the syntax.

Comment: How do I get the value of one of the buttons within that array?  

For instance on click instead of alert(worked) I want to get alert(buttonClicked.val())?

Comment: Is there a way to do this but also dynamically add a different background color to each button???